# Which react native debugger to download for macos, -arm64, -universal, or -x64?

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

As I stated in the question, I cannot figure out which debugger to download from [here](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases).

All I could find was this:

> Go to the Apple Menu and select “About this Mac”. If you have a Core Duo processor, you have a 32-bit CPU. Otherwise (Core 2 Duo, Xeon, i3, i5, i7, anything else), you have a 64-bit CPU.

[Source](https://www.mvorganizing.org/how-do-i-know-if-my-mac-can-run-64-bit/)

Here are the specs of the macbook.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you mention further details? The questions is quite ambiguous. What I get is you want a compatible rn-debbuger for your macOS. Which in your case would be  rn-debugger-macos-x64.zip

Comment: Hello @Hassan1319, yes, I've already installed the one you mention. It's OK, as you may have seen further below, on the answer. But do you know what `universal` is?

Comment: A universal binary runs natively on both Apple silicon and Intel-based Mac computers, because it contains executable code for both architectures. Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary

Comment: @Hassan1319 So I guess I could have used universal too.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get it now!
It's 64, because it's not `code duo`, and it's `Intel`, so it's not `arm`.

So I should download `x64`.

Thanks

But the question kind of still remains... because what is `universal`?